# Android ServerSocket Authentication, how?

Tags: android

I made a serversocket, what is connected to my WIFI's inner IP. 192.168...:8080

i'd like to make a basic authentication, how Can i do that? (name, pass authentication)

Answer (score 1):

finally i made it, all source is here:

http://code.google.com/p/android-simple-httpserver-camerapicture/